# Why an Entry control do not receive the input from user in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, grid, maps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwbP8.png)I want to implement the xamarin essentials map, but with a floating search for the pins that will appear on this map. I'm using a grid to divide the grid's rows and thus use the first row for the map and the second to show a cardview related to the selected pin. I put the search control in row 0 so that it seems to float on the map.

I couldn't get the focus of the search control to work. I don't know if I'm implementing the InputTransparent property correctly.

Any ideas?

```
<Grid InputTransparent="False">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <maps:Map 
                        x:Name="map"   
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        MapType="Street"
                        HasZoomEnabled="True"
                        IsShowingUser="True"
                        InputTransparent="False"
                        MoveToLastRegionOnLayoutChange="false"
                        >
                    </maps:Map>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" InputTransparent="True">
                        <Frame
                            Margin="20,40,20,0"
                            Padding="0"
                            BorderColor="{StaticResource BlackColor}"
                            CornerRadius="8"
                            HeightRequest="35">
                            <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    HeightRequest="20"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    Source="ic_search_bar"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    WidthRequest="20" />
                                <controls:CustomEntry
                                    x:Name="entrySearch"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    FontSize="14"
                                    HeightRequest="35"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                    Keyboard="Text"
                                    Placeholder="¿Qué se te antoja hoy?"
                                    PlaceholderColor="#979797"
                                    ReturnCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"
                                    InputTransparent="False"
                                    ReturnType="Search"
                                    Text="{Binding SearchText}"
                                    TextChanged="entrySearch_TextChanged"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                <Image
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    HeightRequest="15"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    Source="ic_clear_search.png"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    WidthRequest="15">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClearSearchCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
```

I try to use the property in many parts of the code

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.inputtransparent?view=xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

From the docs on [InputTransparent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.inputtransparent?view=xamarin-forms)

> true if neither the element nor its children should receive input and
> should, instead, pass inputs to the elements that are visually behind
> the current visual element

Your stackLayout is transparent so it’s children, including the Entry, are also transparent

Answer (score 0):

1. You might be thinking `InputTransparent` does the opposite of what it actually does. `True` makes an area effectively invisible to touch; touch goes through it.

If you want an element to be touchable, it has to be "False". BUT all its ancestors must also NOT BLOCK touch.

2. If you really mean "True", but you have children you want to click on, do this:

```xml
<SomeLayoutNameHere InputTransparent="True" CascadeInputTransparent="False" ...>
```

That allows children to specify whether they can receive touch (InputTransparent=False), or are invisible to touch (=True).

"False" is the default.